# Regarding security, AngularJS web application.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, authentication, web-applications

I am currently broadening my horizons here. Generally I am a software engineer and I focus on system level code. A colleague has introduced me to the joys of JS and HTML5. I have had a considerably enjoyable experience with it.

My current project is a Blog application. I need a blog site, I don't want to use Wordpress, and this would give me a really good, rounded experience with the Angular framework. I have already written one Angular App, but this one will require a login section.

The problem: I need to place a restriction on users that have not been authenticated on certain pages. That way even if they type that page in specifically in the URL, they will still be denied access to it's data. Once a user is authenticated the page will appear in the list automagically, but that would not stop them from trying the URL directly.

The "Solution": I have read several articles on this matter. The common answer is to have JS check `if(user.auth){show content} else {block}`. However this approach concerns me from a security standpoint. Could an attacker not just go into the inspection editor and set user.auth to true and then gain access to restricted pages that way?

Ultimately I think my question is what is the best, secure convention of handling user restriction based on authentication in an AngularJS Application? Is this a task that I need to offload to a back-end language and have that back-end language push the page data forward?

Much Thanks, 
Andrew

Comment: yes, an attacker can use inspection editor and modify your js values. But you should also validate on the server to load proper data. And he can't use inspection for that. As any security concern regarding to js, you should validate also in the backend side. Also, you could minify/obfuscate your js to add some complexity to the attacker)

Comment: In addition to the above info, in some cases we need to set a token with some name in cookie once user logged in, while calling the service browser will automatically append all the token info to request. based on the token you need to validate user authorization and access.

Comment: Thank you this is all very good information, So no matter what the attack is going to be able to access my page. However, my server software will not push any sensitive data to the web page if they do not see the "token" in the get request. Am I understanding that properly? (Combing both of your comments)

Comment: yes, You are correct and you can read more about security [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security)